# using Google Analytics cookie data to populate Custom Variables with the asynchronous ga.js snippet

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

I am in the process of implementing an attribution solution where the GA cookie ID is passed back into GA as a custom variable a la the instructions here:

http://www.analytics-ninja.com/blog/2011/02/multi-touch-attribution-with-google-analytics.html

The issue I am running into is that with the new asynchronous ga.js code snippet the GA cookie ID is not actually assigned prior to the custom variable value being identified in a '_gaq.push' function. This means that you would not be able to pass the GA cookie ID until the second page load in the session.

Is there any workaround to this where you can require the GA cookie ID be set prior to the Custom Variable being defined?